# Python asyncio response time

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to learn asyncio and aiohttp. I have the following code to query for a bunch of URLs using asyncio.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

sync def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    urls = [
            'http://yahoo.com',
            'https://google.com',
            'http://bing.com'
        ]
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(fetch(session, url))
        htmls = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for html in htmls:
            print(html[:100] + "\n")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How do I get the response time for each asynchronous query? My first idea was to just use a timer, but I don't know how to use that in this situation. I've tried searching for if anybody has done something similar, but can't find anything.

Comment: You can record the time before starting the request, calculate the time difference when the request is completed and return the difference together with the HTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    """[Coroutine to send HTTP request to URLs provided]

    Args:
        session ([aiohttp Client Session object]): [session object]
        url ([string]): [URL to query]

    Returns:
        [list]: [response url, status and time taken]
    """
    tic = time.perf_counter() # Start timer
    try:
        response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url, timeout=10)
        toc = time.perf_counter() # Stop timer
        time_taken  = toc - tic # Calculate time taken to get response
        response.raise_for_status()
        print("URL : ", url)
        print("HTTP Status : ", response.status)
        print(f"Time taken : {time_taken:4f} seconds")
        print()
        return str(response.url), response.status, time_taken
    
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        logging.error(http_err)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(err)
```